# How do I lock my mac without the screen going dark or going to the screensaver?

Tags: macos

When I used Alfred's Lock command my mac locks and shows a screen with a password prompt. I want to know if I can do this on machines that don't have Alfred installed. Is there a way to do by perhaps creating an automator service?

Comment: You could log out... if you select the button the reopens the last windows you have open it will work. It's not pretty, though

Comment: I do not use Alfred, so all I can offer is... you can use `/System/Library/CoreServices/"Menu Extras"/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend` in a Run Shell Script _action_ in an Automator Service and assign it a keyboard shortcut or use it in an AppleScript _script_ from the AppleScript menu on the Apple menu bar or and AppleScript app or a _bash_ script wrapped with Platypus, etc. Have a look at: [How to lock your Mac screen with a keyboard shortcut](http://www.macyourself.com/2013/01/27/how-to-lock-your-mac-screen-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Automator workflow with a Run Shell Script action containing:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

Comment: @user3439894 All Automator documents are workflows, a service is still a workflow; the question did not specify a keyboard shortcut had to be used. I did not see your comment likely because I had this question open prior to your comment and didn't load them before posting my answer.